# receive dd/mm/yyyy from json, but when put in jquery the result is an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, unrecognized-selector

as stated i receive as result of ajax call an objet in JSON with a parameter set as

`"datefrmt":"dd/mm/yyyy"`

when i try to use this value, that should be a string, don't know why but jquery gives an "uncaught syntax error " in console, resulting in stopping js execution.
I tried parsing the string in every way I know, but even if i use

```
console.log($(thisdateformat).datefrmt)
```

the result is

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: mm/dd/yyyy`
How can I use this string? Thanks

Comment: If `thisdateformat` is your JSON data, then why are you "jqueryfying" it by doing `$(thisdateformat)` ? Why not just `thisdateformat.datefrmt` ?

Comment: Hmmm I seeing that you want to get the value in "datefrmt" but how I can see you're invoking a selector with jquery "$()". Use   `thisdateformat.datefrmt` to get these value. Because javascript trying to find the DOM element with the value into `thisdateformat` then trying to access to the property called `datefrmt` that not exist.

Comment: sorry there is an error in paste mismatching all:

'console.log($(this.datefrmt))'

Answer (score 0):

on the success calback of your jquery ajax call :

success: function (response) {
console.log(response.d.datefrmt);

Because the ajax call response has a property d that holds the answer from the back end
if the answer is {"datefrmt":"dd/mm/yyyy"}
then you access the answer via response.d
and every property of response.d by it's property response.d["datefrmt"] or response.d.datefrmt;

Comment: hi sorry there was an error in copy/paste 

'console.log($(this.datefrmt))'  results in the error.

Comment: Because you pasted something you haven't analysed... have a nice day